# Error while installing textblob on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, textblob

I'm trying to install textblob on my system. By following the documentation, I had run the command

```
pip3 install -U textblob
```

But while running the command, I'm getting an error like this.

[image: Error message while installing textblob]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pip install` attempts to write files to `/usr/local`, as seen in the error message. You should run it from the `root` user.

Comment: Why not `pip install --user`?